# Execute and POST data to a PHP script from a PHP script without waiting and no exec

Tags: php

I have 2 scripts called "scriptA.php" and "scriptB.php"

I need to be able to start "scriptB.php" from within "scriptA.php" and make it so the browser isn't waiting for "scriptB.php" to fully complete. I don't want to wait for the script to fully finish, I just want it to finish on its own. I still need to be able to do a POST or to pass data from "scriptA.php" to "scriptB.php" when the script is being executed to be ran.

I can **NOT** use exec, shell_exec or any variation of command line.

***EDIT - Trying cURL option***

Here are my 2 scripts...

scriptA.php

```
    $url = 'scriptB.php';
    $data = array('foo'=>'bar',
          'baz'=>'boom',
          'cow'=>'milk',
          'php'=>'hypertext processor');

     $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'curl');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

scriptB.php

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
$fp = fopen("myTexts.txt","wb");

    $content = "blah ->" . $_GET['foo'];
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
    exit;
```

scriptB.php isn't being called.  I called scriptB.php to test to make sure it works, and when I go to the page directly it does work.  it does write to the file correctly.  Just when i run scriptA.php it isn't being executed.

Comment: You could use `pcntl_fork()` to fork a child process that uses cURL.

Comment: Quick search around the web on this still shows that exec is required with this.  I can't use exec

Comment: You don't need `exec` to perform an HTTP POST request, you do it with cURL.

Comment: PHP isn't good at multi-threading, by design. Due, in part, to its stateless nature. As a result "multi-threaded" processes can be quite fragile. I would advise creating a web-service for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in couple ways:

- Use standard PHP `fork` functions: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-fork.php
- Use external solution like `German` or `RabbitMQ`
- Use framework queue mechanizm. For example see it in Laravel: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues
- Create cronjob that will run your `scriptB` after some event in your system (for example you can create special `env` table that crontab will be process and run `scriptB` after each insert into this table)

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work finally using cURL so props to Barmar for pointing me into the right direction.

```
    //set POST variables
$url = 'scriptB.php';
$fields = array(
                        'foo' => urlencode('bar'),
                        'fname' => urlencode($first_name),
                        'title' => urlencode($title),
                        'company' => urlencode($institution),
                        'age' => urlencode($age),
                        'email' => urlencode($email),
                        'phone' => urlencode($phone)
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

I found this working example from: http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Also on scriptB.php I was doing a "$_GET" instead of a "$_POST"

Thank you everyone for your input!